# Create Widget using Listview in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-widget

i am new widget. i studied some tutorial about widget using texview and button. i cant know more about using listview. there is one xml file named list_item.xml

list_item_xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textStyle="bold" >
  </TextView>
```

and code for an activty

AndroidListViewActivity.java

```
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

    // Binding Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));
    }}
```

how do make this activity as widget in android.

Answer (score 0):

refer this you will get all idea

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget

Comment: any other example pls?

Comment: this one is best, you will get everything from this